# what is the use of qw(:ALL) in perl

Tags: perl

I know about `qw()` function but I have seen at many places the use of `qw(:ALL)`.

What is the advantage of using this and where can I find examples of the use of `qw(:ALL)` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`qw(:ALL)` means exactly the same as `(":ALL")`. It's simply a one item list consisting of a single four character string — colon, capital A, capital L, capital L. Nothing exciting.

A lot of Perl modules offer functions that can be imported into your namespace. For example, the `Carp` module offers functions like `croak` and `confess`. Many such modules allow you to specify a list of functions you want to import:

```
use Carp "confess", "croak", "cluck";
use Carp qw( confess croak cluck );      # this means the same, but looks cleaner
```

Some modules allow you to specify something like `":ALL"` or `":all"` or `"-all"` in that list to indicate you wish to import all the functions they have to offer. [File::Spec::Functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) is an example of a module that does this:

```
use File::Spec::Functions ":ALL";
use File::Spec::Functions qw( :ALL );    # means the same again
```

The reason for the colon is to make it clearer that you're not requesting to import a function called `ALL` (such a function could exist - indeed, [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) provides a function called `all`). There's no technical reason for it; just convention. It would be perfectly possible to write a module so that:

```
use Foo::Bar "ALL";
```

... imported all the functions from Foo::Bar. But people don't do that because tradition.

Comment: Specifically, the colon is a convention of the commonly used `Exporter` module for exporting a list of names associated with the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Some modules use `:ALL` as a parameter to their `import` method to export all possible functions. See [File::Spec::Functions](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) for an example.

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(:ALL);
print tmpdir();
```